# check specific values in a dataframe and make the sum

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to make the sum of each 'Group' which have at least one 'Customer' with an 'Active' Bail.

Sample Input :

```
    Customer ID  Group     Bail       Amount
0    23453       NAFNAF    Active     200
1    23849       LINDT     Active     350
2    23847       NAFNAF    Inactive   100
3    84759       CARROUF   Inactive   20
```

For example 'NAFNAF' has 2 customers, including one with an active bail.

Output expected :

```
NAFNAF : 300
LINDT : 350
TOTAL ACTIVE: 650
```

I don't wanna change the original dataframe

Comment: `df2 = df.groupby('Group').sum()` something like this perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by *I don't wanna change the original dataframe*? You don't want to override the existing data?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to override the existing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(df.assign(Bail=df.Bail.eq('Active'))
   .groupby('Group')[['Bail', 'Amount']].agg('sum')
   .loc[lambda d: d['Bail'].ge(1), ['Amount']]
)
```

output:

```
        Amount
Group         
LINDT      350
NAFNAF     300
```

Full output with total:

```
df2 = (
 df.assign(Bail=df.Bail.eq('Active'))
   .groupby('Group')[['Bail', 'Amount']].agg('sum')
   .loc[lambda d: d['Bail'].ge(1), ['Amount']]
)

df2 = pd.concat([df2, df2.sum().to_frame('TOTAL').T])
```

output:

```
        Amount
LINDT      350
NAFNAF     300
TOTAL      650
```

Comment: @Corralien congrats on the legendary btw ;)

Comment: @Corralien I don't either :p on the computer now btw, much easier

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean mask of `Group` with at least one active lease:

```
m = df['Group'].isin(df.loc[df['Bail'].eq('Active'), 'Group'])
out = df[m]
```

At this point, your filtered dataframe looks like:

```
>>> out
   Customer ID   Group      Bail  Amount
0        23453  NAFNAF    Active     200
1        23849   LINDT    Active     350
2        23847  NAFNAF  Inactive     100
```

Now you can use `groupby` and `sum`:

```
out = df[m].groupby('Group')['Amount'].sum()
out = pd.concat([out, pd.Series(out.sum(), index=['TOTAL ACTIVE'])])

# Output
LINDT           350
NAFNAF          300
TOTAL ACTIVE    650
dtype: int64
```